# Populating a pages html div elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am completing the project: https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/pop_up_penguins/ which allows a user to click on 8 penguins within a page. However i'm trying to populate the page in javascript rather than html such that a player can easily adjust the number of penguins within the game.

I was thinking to first build an array from some user selected number.

```
penguinarray[count];
```

Then use a for loop to repeatedly place each penguin based on the size of the array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < penguinarray.length; i++) {
    document.createElement("penguin1");
}
```

Im not sure however how I can still randomize all the different types of penguins and the snow mounds from the 8 available, or allow the page to change given a different number of penguins.

Comment: Do you have images for penguin 9 ? Or do you plan on starting again at penguin 1 ?

Comment: @klugjo I dont, I was hoping to start again at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow the **user** to specify how many penguins there should be with the **[`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)** method:

```
var penguinCount = prompt("How many penguins should there be?");
```

In order to randomise the **type** of penguin, you'd call **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)** to grab a random number between `1` and `8`, and affix that number to the end of the word `penguin` when creating your elements.

The following will create as many penguins as is specified by the user, each with a random class between `penguin1` and `penguin8`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < penguinCount.length; i++) {
  document.createElement("penguin" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8));
}
```

The same can be done for the snow mounds as well; just make use of a second variable :)

However, assuming the only difference between the penguins is their image, it would be to make use of a **single** class of `.penguin`, and instead randomise the background image when creating the element for said penguin, which can be done with the **[`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** property:

```
for(var i = 0; i < penguinCount.length; i++) {
  var penguin = document.createElement("penguin");
  penguin.style.backgroundImage = "url('penguin'" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8) + "'.png')";
}
```

Doing the latter would mean you'd only need a single class for all the penguins, significantly cutting down on your CSS :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/f1n0190a/1/

Since you deleted the other post, I will just post the answer here, because the question is similar anyway :)

You should practically handle dropdown change event and/or have another button to create those penguins.

```
$("#create-penguin").on("click", function() {

  $(".penguin-list").empty();

  // create penguin
  var numberSelected = $("#penguinsSelected").val();
  for(var i = 0; i < numberSelected; i++) {
    var penguinNo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8);
    var penguin = $("<div>").addClass("penguin" + penguinNo).html("penguin" + penguinNo);
    $(".penguin-list").append(penguin);
  }

});
```

```js
  var maxPenguin = 64;

  //This code will run after page loads
  $(function() {

    // dropdown 2-64 possible elements
    for (var i = 2; i < maxPenguin; i++) {
      $("#penguinsSelected").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }

  });
    
    $(".yeti").mousedown(function() {
        alert("Yaaaarrrr!");
        // yetiClicked();
    });

  $("#create-penguin").on("click", function() {
     
      $(".penguin-list").empty();
      
   // create penguin
      var numberSelected = $("#penguinsSelected").val();
      for(var i = 0; i < numberSelected; i++) {
       var penguinNo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8);
        var penguin = $("<div>").addClass("penguin" + penguinNo).html("penguin" + penguinNo);
        $(".penguin-list").append(penguin);
      }
      
  });
```

```css
/*This style  gives the body element in our HTML a cool blue background color*/

body {
  background-color: #ccf5f5;
}


/*This styles the div in the HTML that contains and centers our penguin game*/

#gameholder {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/*This styles the title div in or HTML*/

#title {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  /*This property embeds an image into the background of our div*/
  background-image: url('media/penguin_title.png');
}


/*This pseudo class is applied when the mouse hovers over the 1st penguin div*/

.penguin1:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_1_hover.png');
  /*This property changes our cursor to a pointer indicating an interactive element*/
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*This pseudo class is applied when our 1st penguin div is clicked by the mouse button*/

.penguin1:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_1.png');
}


/*This is the style for our 1st penguin div*/

.penguin1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_1.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 2nd penguin div.*/

.penguin2:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_2_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin2:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_2.png');
}

.penguin2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_2.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 3rd penguin div.*/

.penguin3:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_3_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin3:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_3.png');
}

.penguin3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_3.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 4th penguin div.*/

.penguin4:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_4_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin4:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_4.png');
}

.penguin4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_4.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 5th penguin div.*/

.penguin5:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_5_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin5:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_5.png');
}

.penguin5 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_5.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 6th penguin div.*/

.penguin6:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_6_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin6:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_6.png');
}

.penguin6 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_6.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 7th penguin div.*/

.penguin7:hover {
  background-image: url('mound_7_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin7:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_7.png');
}

.penguin7 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_7.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our 8th penguin div.*/

.penguin8:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_8_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin8:active {
  background-image: url('media/penguin_8.png');
}

.penguin8 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_8.png');
}


/*These are the styles for our yeti div.*/

.yeti:hover {
  background-image: url('media/mound_9_hover.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yeti:active {
  background-image: url('media/yeti.png');
}

.yeti {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('media/mound_9.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Number of Penguins</span>
<select id="penguinsSelected" name="Number of Penguins"></select>
<button id="create-penguin">Create</button>
<!--This is the frame for our game. It holds and centers all our other elements-->
<div id="gameholder">
  <!--This holds the title image-->
  <div id="title"></div>
  <!--This holds our penguins and yeti-->
  <div class="penguin">PENGUIN</div>
  <div class="yeti">YETI</div>
  <div class="penguin-list">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had reposted the question with JsFiddle myself to be more clear, i'll try this using images referenced in the css file.