# Displaying html div class elements repeatedly based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having trouble using the value of of a dropdown selection to display elements within a page. Im trying to use the number given by a user in a dropdown to repeatedly display a 1 of 8 random "penguin" images. Here I can initially get the first value of the dropdown however I want the page to change once a new value is selected. I also cant seem to get my 2nd for loop here to display each image. Only my html yeti class appears.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    //This code will run after the page loads
    $(function() {
        var maxPenguin = 64;
        var penguinCount = 8;

      for (var i = 2; i < maxPenguin; i++) {
        $('select').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');  
      }

    penguinCount = document.getElementById("penguinsSelected").value; 
      alert(penguinCount);
    });

    $(function displayPenguins(penguinCount){
        for(var i = 0; i < penguinCount; i++) {
            var penguin = document.createElement("penguin" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8));
            document.body.appendChild(penguin);
        }
    })


    $(".yeti").mousedown(function() {
        alert("Yaaaarrrr!");
        yetiClicked();
    });

});
```

It may be easier if I ran it without JQuery

Comment: What is the point of nesting multiple DOM ready checks?

Comment: @silverfin, how many questions you're going to create and delete for this quest of yours. I just answered 1 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625944/populating-a-pages-html-div-elements-using-javascript

Comment: @SudarpoChong apologies was trying to restate question more clearly

Comment: @Silverfin, OK I answered again here using the same fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/f1n0190a/1/

You should practically handle dropdown change event and/or have another button to create those penguins.

#### Step 1

On document ready, create dropdown penguins. Your code is already working for this.

```
    // dropdown 2-64 possible elements
      for (var i = 2; i < maxPenguin; i++) {
        $("#penguinsSelected").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
      }
```

#### Step 2

Handle dropdown change event or button click event

`$("#create-penguin").on("click", function()`

OR

`$("#penguinsSelected").on("change", function() {`

Hope you get the ideas.

```
$("#create-penguin").on("click", function() {

  $(".penguin-list").empty();

  // create penguin
  var numberSelected = $("#penguinsSelected").val();
  for(var i = 0; i < numberSelected; i++) {
    var penguinNo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8);
    var penguin = $("<div>").addClass("penguin" + penguinNo).html("penguin" + penguinNo);
    $(".penguin-list").append(penguin);
  }

});
```

### EDIT

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/q4zqa6cd/2/

If your `yeti` div is inside `#gameholder`, you can use this event handler to be able to add handler for dynamically created `yeti`

```
$("#gameholder").on("mousedown", ".yeti", function() {
    alert("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
});
```

Comment: Ive replicated your solution on JsFiddle but for some reason running it offline doesnt seem to run the numberSelected loop.

Comment: This also prevents the yeti onclick alert from running.

Comment: I must have been missing a closing bracket, here is my updated jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q4zqa6cd/ however the alert still does not seem to work.

Comment: is `yeti` inside `penguin` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pure js approach as you wanted. I hope it's self explanatory.

```js
let imgSources = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/SGI-2016-South_Georgia_%28Fortuna_Bay%29%E2%80%93King_penguin_%28Aptenodytes_patagonicus%29_04.jpg/1200px-SGI-2016-South_Georgia_%28Fortuna_Bay%29%E2%80%93King_penguin_%28Aptenodytes_patagonicus%29_04.jpg","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/South_Shetland-2016-Deception_Island%E2%80%93Chinstrap_penguin_%28Pygoscelis_antarctica%29_04.jpg/1200px-South_Shetland-2016-Deception_Island%E2%80%93Chinstrap_penguin_%28Pygoscelis_antarctica%29_04.jpg","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Aptenodytes_forsteri_-Snow_Hill_Island%2C_Antarctica_-adults_and_juvenile-8.jpg/220px-Aptenodytes_forsteri_-Snow_Hill_Island%2C_Antarctica_-adults_and_juvenile-8.jpg"];

document.getElementById("dropdown").onchange = displayImages;

function displayImages() {
let nodes = document.getElementById("dispImage");
  removeAllChilds(nodes)
  let pengvalue = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  if(pengvalue != "choose") {  
     for(i=0;i<pengvalue;i++) {
       var img = new Image();      
        img.className = 'center';
        img.width = 300;
        img.height = 300;
        img.src = imgSources[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgSources.length)];
        document.getElementById("dispImage").appendChild(img);
  
     }
  }
}

function removeAllChilds(node) {
  while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="dispImage">

</div>
```